# What does the quo method do?

Tags: ruby

Consider the following methods, found in the [byar gem](https://github.com/florish/byar/blob/master/lib/byar.rb#L48-L60):

```
##
# Calculate lower boundary for observed cases
def self.lower_bound(obs, z_value = Z_VALUE)
  return 0 if obs == 0
  obs * (1 - 1.quo(9 * obs) - z_value.quo(3 * Math.sqrt(obs))) ** 3
end

##
# Calculate upper boundary for observed cases
def self.upper_bound(obs, z_value = Z_VALUE)
  obs = obs + 1
  obs * (1 - 1.quo(9 * obs) + z_value.quo(3 * Math.sqrt(obs))) ** 3
end
```

I would like to port these methods to Javascript, but I am unsure what `quo` does.

Comment: Did you Google it? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Numeric.html#method-i-quo

Comment: I did found that, but I don't really get it.
Does: 
    `1.quo(9 * obs)` in Ruby 
Convert to:
    `Math.floor(1/(9*obs))` in JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`quo`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Numeric.html#method-i-quo) is a method defined on the `Numeric` class (and redefined in the [`Float`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Float.html#method-i-quo) class), which calculates the *quotient* of the receiver with the given argument. In other words, `x.quo(y)` is roughly equivalent to `x / y`, but more *precise*.

The difference here comes in when `x` and `y` are `Fixnum`s (ie. an integer value):

```
> (1 / 2)
=> 0
> (1 / 2).class
=> Fixnum
> 1.quo(2)
=> (1/2)
> 1.quo(2).class
=> Rational
> 1.quo(2.5)
=> 0.4
> 1.quo(2.5).class
=> Float
```

Basically, `quo` ensures that the result of the division is expressed accurately by returing a [`Rational`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Rational.html) or `Float`, depending on the receiver and argument.

In Javascript, there isn't a distinction between different types of numbers, and division returns a floating point number already if necessary, so the first method can be expressed as:

```
obs * Math.pow(1 - 1 / (9 * obs) - z_value / (3 * Math.sqrt(obs)), 3)
```

Comment: The answer is almost correct, but you misplaced the `Math.pow` a bit.
It should be: `obs * (1 - 1 / (9 * obs)) - Math.pow(z_value / (3 * Math.sqrt(obs)), 3)`. But thank you very much, this helped me a lot!

Comment: Are you sure about that? The first method in your question boils down to `obs * (something) ** 3`, which is equivalent to `obs * Math.pow(something, 3)` in javascript

Comment: Yes I am sure. The bound-values get to low otherwise.
It's is because of the `-` in the code:
`obs * (1 - 1.quo(9 * obs) - z_value.quo(3 * Math.sqrt(obs))) ** 3` will become `obs * a - b ** 3`. So only b needs to be in the `Math.pow`.

Comment: I am very sorry, you are correct. I missed the `()` surrounding the middle part. Your answer is the correct one, my mistake!